# Cat Stevens Numbers Cartoon?

Tags: history, rock

I was recently listening to Cat Steven's [*Numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_(Cat_Stevens_album)) album, and remembered watching a cartoon special on US television based on this story when I was a kid. This was obviously quite a while ago in the 70's when the album came out.

Googling the album, I see references to a booklet featuring pen-and-ink illustrations by Cat, but nothing mentioning a cartoon.

Does anyone else remember this?

Comment: There sure isn't any evidence for a cartoon so I am starting to think this is a miss-remembrance of the album. I guess I had a good imagination at that age...

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a Cat Stevens cartoon about the Numbers album, however, I was able to find a cartoon that was released in 1977 featuring the 1971 song Moonshadow. You can find it on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0awe6OJB0o).

Reading into the *Numbers* album, it seems as though it was a critical and commercial failure (at least compared to Stevens' previous records), so I'd find it unlikely that his record labels would allow/fund the creation of a cartoon for such an album. This makes me think that you might be confusing the release of *Numbers* in 1975 with the cartoon from 1977, since they came out around the same time.

All of this having been said, I could be quite wrong, as this is all I was able to find online, and I wasn't alive when any of these things were first released. But even if this isn't the correct answer, hopefully it points you in the right direction!

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. After looking at the linked video, it did not jar any memories and I do not think it is what I was remembering. Thanks.